# How to have a 2d array that have characters and numbers in them in (c)

Tags: c

So I'm trying to print out a 2d array (`double array[2][3]`) that has decimal numbers and characters something like that

```
3.4  E 
5.6  R 
7.8  T
```

Numbers in row and chrachters in the other row

Comment: Create a `struct` (`struct { double d; char c; };`) or have two separate arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't , this is some thing you want or not:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int  main()
{
    double array[2][3] = {{2.5, 3.6, 4.2}, {'R', 'A', 'Q'}};

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("%lf ", array[0][i]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("%c ", (char)array[1][i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
2.500000 3.600000 4.200000 
R A Q
```

As the comment, you should use the struct that contains two types (one for `char`, one for `double`) because cast from `double` to `char` as i did is not recommended.